# How to see the output of Python's hypothesis library

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

When using the [hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library and performing unit testing, how can I see what instances the library is trying on my code?

Example

```
from hypothesis import given
import hypothesis.strategies as st

@given(st.integers())
def silly_example(some_number):
    assert some_number > 0
```

The question is: how do I print / see the `some_number` variable, generated by the library?

Comment: If you just wish to see the value this library tries, you can add a print statement in the function itself, `print(some_number)`

Comment: @LakshayGarg this does not print during `pytest` unit testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a print statement or logging statement before the `assert`:

```
import logging
from hypothesis import given
import hypothesis.strategies as st

log_filename = 'debug.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_filename, level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@given(st.integers())
def silly_example(some_number):
    logger.debug('silly_example(%s) called', some_number)
    assert some_number > 0
```

By using logging instead of print statements, you can turn off all logging 
simply by changing the logging level. If you change `logging.DEBUG` to `logging.INFO`:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_filename, level=logging.INFO)
```

then `logger.debug` will no longer emit records.

Comment: When formatting the logger function like so, I get a sonarcube error: `Use % formatting in logging functions and pass the % parameters as arguments `. Maybe it's best to use another formatting?

Comment: In that case, try: `logger.debug('silly_example(%s) called', some_number)`.

Comment: The problem with logging or printing from a Hypothesis test is that the output does not distinguish between test cases, so it can be hard to tell which lines came from a particular failing case.  That's why hypothesis provides the `note` and `event` functions to emit information that it can filter or summarise for you.

Answer (score 8):

[See here](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/details.html) - either the `note` function and `--hypothesis-verbosity=verbose`, or the `event` function and `--hypothesis-show-statistics` should do the trick.

Comment: Where do I write the `--hypothesis-verbosity=verbose`? I tried and still with no luck.

Comment: Like `pytest --hypothesis-verbosity=verbose my_tests.py` - if you're not using Pytest, you can use [`@settings` as a decorator, or the profiles mechanism](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html).

Comment: I get an error when I do this though: `usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]` and `pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --hypothesis-verbosity=verbose`

Comment: Ah, you probably just need to update Hypothesis - the option was added in version 3.79.0, on 2018-10-23.

Answer (score 1):

--hypothesis-verbosity=debug and --hypothesis-verbosity=verbose both works for me - but I have to get pytest not to capture the output as well, with a -s in front. Looks like this:

```
python -m pytest -s --hypothesis-verbosity=debug tests
```

Answer (score 0):

--hypothesis-verbosity=debug helps to see the output.